# Add a trend line to each of 2 datasets displayed on my power BI bar chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, trendline

I've got a really basic bar chart in PBI.
It has 2 data sets displayed out over the last FY.
I've changed the x axis to numeric values, so that it allowed me to add a trend line.
I would like to add a trend line for data set 1, and then another for data set 2.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't feel like this should be this difficult.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, tt's rather intuitive:

1. With the chart selected go to the **Analytics** tab
2. Set **Trend line** to **On**
3. Set **Combine series** to **Off**

[image]